# Does anyoone has the experience of G Suite SSO with php yii app?

Tags: php, yii, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I am trying to integrate G Suite SSO in my custom yii application. Can anyone help me which steps should i follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to leverage SAML. G Suite would function as the identity provider and has a pretty simple SAML configuration.

Someone has implemented OneLogin's [php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) with Yii... see the Github repo here: [asasmoyo/yii2-saml](https://github.com/asasmoyo/yii2-saml).

Not sure I would recommend using that code so much as taking it as an example of how to implement php-saml within Yii.

Another option to look at would be something like [SimpleSAMLphp](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp), which has very easy mechanism to invoke authentication and then establish a session.